# Looking for a build system that meets a number of criteria

Tags: build-system

I am looking for a build system that meets the following criteria:

1. MUST support dynamic dependencies and dynamic outputs. It should be possible and natural to write recipes relying on build tools that traverse large directory structures looking for inputs, and possibly write an output file for each input file found. The only assumption is that the tool is capable of providing the information about the exact set of inputs it used and outputs it wrote. There are two possible flavors of this capability: either the tool dumps that information to a side channel whenever it is invoked, or there is a special "list" mode of invoking the tool to provide this information in advance. The build system MUST naturally support both flavors, including when the tool supports one flavor for dependencies and the other for outputs.
2. MUST make best effort to utilize this autodependency information for minimal incremental builds.
3. MUST use content hashes rather than timestamps to determine up-to-dateness (this disqualifies e.g. make, ninja, and everything that compiles to ninja).
4. MUST NOT be opinionated: MAY advise against, but MUST NOT outright disallow practices that it deems unsafe from build correctness standpoint. MUST always provide a way for me to say that I am going to take manual responsibility for a given aspect of correctness, or of a factor potentially affecting correctness. In particular, it MUST NOT do any sandboxing whatsoever, and MUST allow recipes to read from anywhere and to write anywhere (this disqualifies eg. tup, bazel).
5. MUST be generic, i.e. developed without a specific narrow use case in mind. It's OK if there are special facilities e.g. for building C/C++ projects, but writing build specs for workflows that the build system's author hadn't foreseen MUST NOT be 20× harder.
6. Writing build specs MUST NOT require learning a hard, paradigmatically alien programming language like Haskell, Prolog or LISP (this disqualifies e.g. shake). It SHOULD NOT require Python or Java. Javascript and shell are OK, but a non-Turing-complete DSL is definitely preferred.
7. This last one is not essential, but the DSL (if used) SHOULD be "shell-first", i.e. if I can invoke a tool by typing the command in the terminal, then I should be able to paste that command (almost) verbatim into the build spec without extensive escaping, or worse yet, manually tokenizing it into an array of strings.

Comment: I guess that this list of thoroughly specified requirements came after a well thought process, in which you already considered potential build systems. Do you mind listing them and mention which requirements they don't meet?

Comment: I guess that your decision to ignore all 6 of 6 instances where I did just that came after thorough reading of my post. Do you mind listing your reasons why you ignored my listing of make, ninja, everything that compiles to ninja, tup, bazel and shake under precisely those requirements that those build systems don't meet?

Comment: Why sarcasm? I honestly think your question reflects a well thought process, and the build systems just slipped from my eyes, sorry for that. I suggest you to make it bold or salient for the reader's eye in some other way.

Comment: sarcasm aside, now I see why my last company used a propriotary, in-house build system that was such a pain to use and burned a lot of time of a lot of expensive people.

Comment: Beats me; build it.